# Querying embeds_many doesn't return result with interpolation

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a embeds_many field in Postgresql jsonb and I am trying to query it using fragment like this:

```
 def find(key, val) do
     q = from p in Person,
           where: fragment("meta_tags @> ?", ^"'[{\"#{key}\":\"#{val}\"}]'"),
           select: p
     Repo.all(q)
 end
```

I don't understand why hardcoded value in the `fragment("meta_tags @> '[{"type":"test"}]'")` works but will return no result once I use interpolated values from the function input.

The logs are as below:

Not returning result with interpolated string.

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="world_persons" db=15.1ms
SELECT w0."id", w0."name", w0."salutation", w0."original_name",
       w0."gender", w0."dob" w0."email", w0."active",
       w0."inserted_at", w0."updated_at"
FROM "persons" AS w0
WHERE (meta_tags @> $1) ["'[{\"type\":\"test\"}]'"] []
```

With results when I hardcode the value.

```
[debug] QUERY OK source="world_persons" db=5.2ms decode=0.1ms
SELECT w0."id", w0."name", w0."salutation", w0."original_name",
       w0."gender", w0."dob", w0."email", w0."active",
       w0."inserted_at", w0."updated_at"
FROM "persons" AS w0
WHERE (meta_tags @> '[{"type":"test"}]') []
(... results)
```

This won't work with hardcoded value

```
where: fragment("meta_tags @> ?", ^"[{\"type\":\"test\"}]"),
```

This works without the interpolated operator

```
where: fragment("meta_tags @> ?", "[{\"type\":\"test\"}]"),
```

What have I missed in this query to make this work?

Comment: Do you get any error with that query? or just no results?

Comment: No result. Let me update my question for clarity.

Comment: Could you check the logs and post the query that's executed when you hardcode and the query that's executed with interpolation?

Comment: Added debug logs more more clarity. :-)

Comment: Could you try removing the single quotes from the interpolated string? Try `^"[{\"#{key}\":\"#{val}\"}]"`.

Comment: Nop, tried that -- and tried again just now to be sure -- not working.
`...AS w0 WHERE (meta_tags @> $1) ["[{\"type\":\"test\"}]"]`

Comment: How about explicitly casting it to `text` then `jsonb`: `fragment("meta_tags @> ?::text::jsonb", ^"[{\"#{key}\":\"#{val}\"}]")`?

Comment: @Dogbert that casting method work, thanks!
But what went wrong with the interpolation I wonder.

Comment: I think I know why it requires casting, but I don't know why it requires double cast `?::text::jsonb` and just `?::jsonb` doesn't work.

Comment: Just ?::jsonb doesn't work. Why does it requires casting?